# Is it possible to add a constructor afterwards to an existing object? Is it meaningful?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Assuming there is a construct like that:

```
var Foo = {
    someVar : 13,
    someMessage : function () {
        return "Hello";
    }
};
```

I would like to add a construct outside of Foo to initalize someVar, so that following action would be possible:

```
var foo = new Foo (someVar);
```

I know the so called constructor invocation pattern (which I am actually not looking for but I've also here a question):

```
var Foo = function (someVar) {
    this.someVar = someVar;
};

Foo.prototype.getSomeVar = function () {
    return this.someVar;
};

var foo = new Foo ("some content");

console.log (foo.getSomeVar());
```

How can I add a property (someSecondVar) to Foo outside of Foo?

Comment: Good question.. I really do not understand, why some people must to vote it down?

Comment: @adeneo: If you don't get it, you don't have to answer. You don't have to vote down too. Just keep quiet und let people answer, that got it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not instantiate object literal (comparison to other programming languages does not work here) in JavaScript unfortunately. It would be (maybe) a good idea, you could save some paperwork.

"Constructor invocation pattern" is a try in the right direction and you can simply add a property in this way:

```
Foo.prototype.someSecondVar = "what ever";
```

EDIT: You can not instantiate an object literal but you can make a new object and select the object, that should be its prototype (from Douglas Crockford):

Please study the following example:

```
var Person = {
    "name" : "Max",
    "age" : 30,
    "children" : ["Susi", "Ben"]
};

Object.create = function (obj) {
    var F = function () {};
    F.prototype = obj;
    return new F();
};

var Person2 = Object.create(Person);
Person2.name = "John";
Person2.age = 40;
Person2.children = ["Sara"];

Person.city = "New York";

console.log(Person2);
```

The output shows 2 important things:

1. The new object has all properties from the old one
2. If you add some properties to old object afterwards, the newones will get it automatically

[image: Object.Create -> The output]

Answer (score 1):

attaching a property is simple and can be done just like how you would attach a function to a construct:

```
Foo.prototype.someSecondVar = 0;
Foo.prototype.someThirdVar = "blah";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be accomplished by using the `.prototype` of the object. Keep in mind, altering the prototype is computationally expensive usually and it also alters *all* objects that are instances of the object who's prototype you're altering, which may or may not be what you want.

You can add a property the way Husman mentions in his answer.

If you really need to instantiate it and can't just place a value there with a custom function, look into getters and setters: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

by using getters/setters, you can add some conditional for whatever case you need the value of the property for, thus emulating a constructur, in a way.

Overall however, I'd advise rethinking your code structure. These kinds of approaches generally can only be justified if what you want to do is quite complicated and are usually not necessary if you re-think your code.